# Find distribution of data set

Tags: distributions, dataset, fitting

I have the following data set and would like to know how I can find an arrival distribution that best matches the data set. To clarify the data below - from Train 1, 173 passengers reached the queue between 0-15 min, it took 16-30 min for 308 passengers from the same train to reached the queue, etc. 
Any help is greatly appreciated. Many thanks!

[image]

Comment: I need to figure out the arrival pattern (distribution that fits it) so I can generate somewhat the same pattern. Not sure if frequency plays a role here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You probably need to treat each train separately.

   - Notice that the distribution of some of the trains differ drastically from each other.

     - The data for Train 14 may come from an exponential distribution.
     - The data for Train 11 have peaks at the beginning AND the end. It may be difficult to choose a parametric form here.
2. Arrival time is an inherently continuous random variable, but your data is discretized on coarse intervals. One way of treating this, if you're willing to assume a distribution, is to find the value of the parameters which maximize the goodness of fit. Let's take Train 14 as an example.

The empirical probabilities are as follows:

$$P(X \in I) = 
\begin{cases}
\frac{240}{473} = 0.507 & I = (0, 15] \\
0.226 & I = (15, 30] \\
0.224 & I = (30, 45] \\
0.042 & I = (45, 60] \\
\end{cases}$$

And the corresponding theoretical probabilities (assuming exponential with mean $\lambda$) are:

$$P(X \in (a, b]) = F(b) - F(a) = e^{- a/\lambda} - e^{b/\lambda}$$

If we choose to use $\chi^2$ goodness of fit, then the objective is to minimize the following (over $\lambda$):

$$\chi^2 = \sum\frac{(Emperical_i - Theoretical_i)^2}{Theoretical_i}$$

Here is the R function I use to compute the $\chi^2$ test statistic given the empirical probabilities and a scale parameter $\lambda$.

```
 chisq_arrival <- function(lambda, emp){
  theo <- rep(0, 4)
  cuts <- c(0, 15, 30, 45, 60)
  for(i in 1:4){
    theo[i] <- exp(-cuts[i]/lambda) - exp(-cuts[i+1]/lambda)
  }
  chisq <- sum( (theo-emp)^2/theo )
  return(chisq)  
 }
```

And then we can find the optimal lambda by doing

```
 result <- optim(par=30, fn=chisq_arrival, method='Brent', lower=0, upper=60, emp=emp)$par
```

Which tells us that for Train 14, the best fitting exponential distribution is that with mean $\lambda = 24.36$. Below is a plot of the empirical vs theoretical distribution functions.

[image]

Comment: "Arrival time is an inherently continuous random variable, but your data is discretized on coarse intervals." Data of (# arrivals)/(fixed time interval) counts is different than data of arrival times. For example if the inter-event *waiting* times are exponentially distributed (and independent), the counts will be *Poisson* distributed.

Comment: @GeoMatt22 Sure, but the OP specifically asked: "how I can find an arrival distribution that best matches the data set".

Comment: I agree your interpretation is reasonable, but the OP is a bit ambiguous (IMO, though I did not vote to close :) )

Comment: Maybe poisson is the better way to go.. after all this method will break down for some of the rows in this table.

Comment: Would it be correct to add all the passengers from all the trains for each time interval and then fit that data to a distribution?

Comment: Sure, but that would end up ignoring the fact that the Trains are very different from eachother.